# How do I register List collections in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, kryo

I have a list of type `List<someClassType>` in my Scala code of Spark. How can I register it by using `kryo.register`. I mean what would be the parameters to the `kryo.register` function.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
.register(classOf[List[someClassType]])
```